# Decisive equivalence of collections of probability measures

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, terminology, game-theory

Working on the optimal decision theory in stochastic setting, I've found out that the following notion of equivalence is very useful. Let $(X,\mathscr A)$ be a measurable space, and let $\mathrm b\mathscr A$ denote the space of all bounded measurable functions
$$
  f:(X,\mathscr A)\to(\Bbb R,\mathscr B(\Bbb R)).
$$
Let also $\mathcal P(X,\mathscr A)$ denote the collection of all probability measures on $(X,\mathscr A)$.

> **Definition:** we say that collections $P,Q\subseteq \mathcal P(X,\mathscr A)$ are equivalent, and we write $P\sim Q$ if 
>   $$
>   \sup_{p\in P}\int_\Omega f\;\mathrm dp = \sup_{q\in Q}\int_\Omega f\;\mathrm dq \qquad \forall f\in \mathrm b\mathscr A. \tag{1}
> $$

The relation above is clearly an equivalence relation, and also it does not matter whether we put $\sup$ or $\inf$ in $(1)$. It is useful especially when one wants to show that $Q\subset P$ is a strict subset of $P$, but still $P\sim Q$. However, I am not sure whether that's the only notion of equivalence between the collections of measures, and perhaps $(1)$ already has a different name.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you just asking if there is a name for that relation, or are you looking for a different, but equivalent, formulation?

Comment: @henrique I wonder about the terminology: 1. Does the relation I defined have a different name in the literature? 2. Is the term "equivalence" applied to families of measures used in literature for something distinct from what I defined here.